# Callback function for CheckboxGroup and Button

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to create a visualization with `CheckboxGroup`, which shows the line of the currency in the graph if the checkbox of this currency is activated. In addition i want one Button 'Select all' and one 'Select none' to select all or none currency at once.

By now, I have this code but I get the following error:

> unexpected attribute 'checkbox' to CustomJS, possible attributes are args, code, js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, name, subscribed_events or tags

I would appreciate a check of my code and some help. Thank you

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, FactorRange, CheckboxGroup, CustomJS, Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

...
args = []
code = "active = cb_obj.active;"
for c in range(len(currencies)):
    line = p.line(x='dates', y=currencies[c], line_width=2, alpha=1, name=currencies[c], legend_label=currencies[c], source=source)
    args += [('line'+str(c), line)]
    code += "line{}.visible = active.includes({});".format(c, c)
...

checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=currencies, active=list(range(len(currencies))))

checkbox_group.callback = CustomJS(args={key:value for key,value in args}, checkbox=checkbox_group, code=code)

def callback_button_on():
    checkbox_group.active = list(range(len(currencies)))

def callback_button_off():
    checkbox_group.active = []


select_all = Button(label='Select all')
select_all.on_click(callback_button_on)

select_none = Button(label='Select none')
select_none.on_click(callback_button_off)

group = column(select_all, select_none, checkbox_group)

show(row(group, p))
output_file("Daily_Returns.html")
```

Comment: If you want a quick help in the future **always** provide a **full and executable** code without `...`

Answer (score 0):

A CustomJS callback does not accept arbitrary arguments, but all bokeh models that should be available in the javascript code must be part of the `args` dictionary. Simply add the checkbox group into it:

```
args = []
args.append(("checkbox", checkboxgroup))
code = "active = cb_obj.active;"
...

checkbox_group.callback = CustomJS(args={key:value for key,value in args}, code=code)
```

or if your code has no explicit mention of the checkboxgroup (i tonly uses `cb_obj`) you can also just not pass the checkbox to the CustomJS callback.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for Boekh v2.1.1
There were a few issues with your code:

1. Callback data is only allowed inside `args` dictionary
2. In JS you need to always use `var` for variable declaration => `var active = cb_obj.active`
3. Your Python callbacks for buttons won't work in a stand-alone HTML page. Python callbacks only work in a server app. For your stand-alone HTML page use only JS callbacks => `js_on_click`.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CheckboxGroup, CustomJS, Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

currencies = ['EUR', 'GBP']
data = {'dates': [datetime(2017,1,1) + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,3)], 'EUR': [1.3, 1.1, 1.3], 'GBP': [1.6, 1.7, 1.6]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")

checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=currencies, active=list(range(len(currencies))))
select_all = Button(label='Select all')
select_none = Button(label='Select none')

args = [('checkbox', checkbox_group)]
code = "var active = cb_obj.active;"
for c in range(len(currencies)):
    line = p.line(x='dates', y=currencies[c], line_width=2, alpha=1, name=currencies[c], legend_label=currencies[c], source=source)
    args += [('line'+str(c), line)]
    code += "line{}.visible = active.includes({});".format(c, c)

checkbox_group.js_on_change('active', CustomJS(args={key:value for key,value in args}, code=code))
select_all.js_on_click(CustomJS(args={'checkbox_group': checkbox_group, 'currencies': currencies}, code="checkbox_group.active = Array.from(currencies, (x, i) => i);"))
select_none.js_on_click(CustomJS(args={'checkbox_group': checkbox_group}, code="checkbox_group.active = [];"))

group = column(select_all, select_none, checkbox_group)

show(row(group, p))
```